# How can I map 2 numpy arrays with same indices

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to map 2 numpy arrays as [x, y] similar to what zip does for lists and tuples.

I have 2 numpy arrays as follows:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I am looking for an `output as np.array([[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]])`

I tried this but it maps every value and not with same indices. I can add more if conditions here but is there any other way to do so without adding any more if conditions.

```
res = [arr1, arr2] for a1 in arr1 for a2 in arr2]
```

Comment: Do you want a (1,4,2) array?  3d with that initial size 1 dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [**`np.dstack`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)

> Stack arrays in sequence depth wise (along third axis).

```
np.dstack([arr1, arr2])

array([[[1, 5],
        [2, 6],
        [3, 7],
        [4, 8]]])
```

Comment: I did not know this existed +1

Comment: It's numpy, something always exists ;)

Comment: Thanks @user3483203. I tried the above and I am getting without comma-separated values.

Comment: yeah my input is of this type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Are you positive you are using `dstack` and not `stack`?

Comment: Yes. Here `test = np.dstack([lons, lats])` and my output is ```[[[ 2  3]
  [ 4  6]
  [ 6  9]
  [ 8 12]]]```

Comment: Oh that's just how your stdout represents a numpy array.  The values are separated, don't worry :)  Try converting to a list if you want to verify

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, one way is to use [`numpy.vstack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) followed by [`transpose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html):

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
print(np.vstack([arr1, arr2]).transpose())
#array([[1, 5],
#       [2, 6],
#       [3, 7],
#       [4, 8]])
```

Or you could pass the output of `zip` to the `array` constructor:

```
print(np.array(zip(arr1, arr2)))
#array([[1, 5],
#       [2, 6],
#       [3, 7],
#       [4, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The built in `zip` command is the job for you here.  It'll do exactly what you're asking.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [5,6,7,8]
list(zip(arr1, arr2))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: good approach, but OP is looking for a method specific to `numpy.ndarray` parameters and returns.